# Calculating values based on column names

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have three tables that I need to calculate some factors from. The tables are of the form:

```
t1: id |  height    | weight     | ..
     1 |     180    |    190     | ..

t2: id | adjustmentFactor
     1 |   0.05

t3: attribute | multOrDivide
     height   |     1
     weight   |     0
```

I need to produce a view on these tables of the form:

```
id | adjustedHeight | adjustedWeight...
 1 |     9          |      3800
```

where

```
adjustedAttribute = 
attribute * adjustmentFactor, if multOrDivide = 1 for that attribute,
attribute / adjustmentFactor, if multOrDivide = 0 for that attribute
```

Is there any way to apply these two forms of adjustment depending on the `attributeName` in a SQL query?

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: how many other columns do you have in t1? it would make more sense to formulate t1 as `id|attribute|value`.

Comment: There are hundreds of columns in t1. I agree having the attributes be rows would be more helpful, but the table is already in a pivoted form, and I can't really change the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use a column name as part of a logic statement. Your application would need to construct an SQL statement that specifically inserts those values.